# Question about proving differentiability

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-writing, chain-rule

I'm asked to prove $f\left(x\right)=\left(x\cdot\ln x\right)^{\ln x}$ is differentiable for every x > 1
and calculate it's deriviate.

I have no idea how to approach this question.. Do I need to define a function g that will be the inverse of f?

i.e. $g\left(x\right)=\left(\frac{e^{x}}{x}\right)^{e^{x}}$, prove it's continuous, differential and that it's derivate is not 0 and then use the chain rule?

My attempt:

$f\left(x\right)=\left(x\cdot\ln x\right)^{\ln x}=e^{\ln\left(x\cdot\ln x\right)^{\ln x}}=e^{\left(\ln x\cdot\ln\left(x\cdot\ln x\right)\right)}$

Note that by the algebra of differential functions $e^x,ln(x)$ are differential for every $x > 1$. Therefore $g(x)={\left(\ln x\cdot\ln\left(x\cdot\ln x\right)\right)}$ is also differential for every $x > 1$, and $f$ as a whole is differential for every $x > 1$. Therefore by the chain rule we have

$f'\left(x\right)=\left(e^{\left(\ln x\cdot\ln\left(x\cdot\ln x\right)\right)}\right)^{'}=e^{\left(\ln x\cdot\ln\left(x\cdot\ln x\right)\right)}\cdot\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\cdot\ln\left(x\cdot\ln x\right)\right)+\left(\frac{1}{x\cdot\ln x}\cdot\left(\ln x+1\right)\right)\cdot\ln x\right)$

$=e^{\left(\ln x\cdot\ln\left(x\cdot\ln x\right)\right)}\cdot\left(\left(\frac{\ln\left(x\cdot\ln x\right)}{x}\right)+\left(\frac{\ln^{2}x+\ln x}{x\cdot\ln x}\right)\right)=e^{\left(\ln x\cdot\ln\left(x\cdot\ln x\right)\right)}\cdot\left(\left(\frac{\ln\left(x\right)+\ln\left(\ln x\right)}{x}\right)+\left(\frac{\ln x+1}{x}\right)\right)$

$=e^{\left(\ln x\cdot\ln\left(x\cdot\ln x\right)\right)}\cdot\left(\left(\frac{\ln\left(x\right)+\ln\left(\ln x\right)+\ln x+1}{x}\right)\right)=e^{\left(\ln x\cdot\ln\left(x\cdot\ln x\right)\right)}\cdot\left(\left(\frac{2\ln\left(x\right)+\ln\left(\ln x\right)+1}{x}\right)\right)=e^{\left(\ln x\cdot\ln\left(x\cdot\ln x\right)\right)}\cdot\left(\left(\frac{\ln\left(x^{2}\right)+\ln\left(\ln x\right)+1}{x}\right)\right)=e^{\left(\ln x\cdot\ln\left(x\cdot\ln x\right)\right)}\cdot\left(\left(\frac{\ln\left(x^{2}\cdot\ln x\right)+1}{x}\right)\right)$

Comment: $f(x)=e^{\ln x \ln (x \ln x)}$. Apply Chain rule and product rule.

Comment: Just for fun:

Let 

$$  z=f(u,v)=u^v,$$
$$u=x\ln x,$$
and
$$v=\ln x.$$ 

By the multivariable chain rule,
$$
{dz\over dx}={\partial z\over \partial u}{du\over dx}+{\partial z\over \partial v}{dv\over dx}.
$$

Comment: Thanks but we've just started with differentiability and I have no idea what you did there, and I'm not allowed to use anything we didn't prove haha.

Comment: I've edited my question with an attempt, is there anything I could improve?

Answer (score 0):

if $x \ge e$ then $\ln x \ge 1$ so $x\cdot \ln  x > 0$ and $\ln (x\cdot \ln  x)$ exists and $x\cdot \ln x = e^{\ln (x\cdot \ln  x)}$.

And then $f(x) = (x\cdot \ln x)^{\ln x}= [e^{\ln (x\cdot \ln  x)}]^{\ln x} = e^{\ln x\dot \ln(x\cdot \ln x)}$.

And that can be differentiated by the using the chain rule and the product rule many times.

If we use the notation $exp(x)= e^x$ and $exp'(x) = $ derivative of $exp(x) =$ derivative of $e^x = e^x=exp(x)$ then

First use of chain rule:  $[exp(\ln x\dot \ln(x\cdot \ln x))]' = exp'(\ln x\dot \ln(x\cdot \ln x))\times (\ln x\dot \ln(x\cdot \ln x))' =$

$exp(\ln x\dot \ln(x\cdot \ln x))\times (\ln x\dot \ln(x\cdot \ln x))'=$

$(x\cdot \ln x)^{\ln x} \times (\ln x\dot \ln(x\cdot \ln x))'=$

Now apply the product rule;

$(x\cdot \ln x)^{\ln x} \times [\ln' x\cdot \ln(x\cdot \ln x) + \ln x (\ln(x\cdot \ln x))'=$

$(x\cdot \ln x)^{\ln x} \times [\frac 1x\cdot \ln(x\cdot \ln x) + \ln x (\ln(x\cdot \ln x))'=$

Now apply the chain rule again:

$(x\cdot \ln x)^{\ln x} \times [\frac 1x\cdot \ln(x\cdot \ln x) + \ln x (\ln'(x\cdot \ln x)\times (x\cdot \ln x)')=$

$(x\cdot \ln x)^{\ln x} \times [\frac 1x\cdot \ln(x\cdot \ln x) + \ln x (\frac 1{x\cdot \ln x}\times (x\cdot \ln x)')=$

And use the product rule again

$(x\cdot \ln x)^{\ln x} \times [\frac 1x\cdot \ln(x\cdot \ln x) + \ln x (\frac 1{x\cdot \ln x}\times (x\cdot (\ln x)'+ (x)'\ln x))=$

$(x\cdot \ln x)^{\ln x} \times [\frac 1x\cdot \ln(x\cdot \ln x) + \ln x (\frac 1{x\cdot \ln x}\times (x\cdot\frac 1x+ 1\cdot\ln x))=$

$(x\cdot \ln x)^{\ln x} \times [\frac 1x\cdot \ln(x\cdot \ln x) + \ln x (\frac 1{x\cdot \ln x}\times (1+ \ln x))=$

$(x\cdot \ln x)^{\ln x}[\frac {\ln(x\cdot\ln x)}x + \ln x(\frac 1{x\ln x} + \frac 1x)]$.

Sof $1 < x < e$ we have $x\ln x < 0$ so $\ln (-x\cdot \ln x)$ exists and $x\cdot \ln x= e^{-\ln(-x\ln x)}$.

And do what we did above.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! :) But this seems a bit too complicated for me.. we didn't learn what $exp$ is.. But I've edited my answer with my attempt, did I get something wrong?

Comment: I only used the notation $exp$ so that if I refered  $exp'(quackquackquack)$ yould know I'd mean the derivative of $e^{quackquackquack}$ *with respect to $quackquackquack$* which would be $e^{quackquackquack}$.  If I tried to write $[e^{quackquackquack})'$ it wouldn't be clear if I meant the derivative with respect to $quackquackquack$ or with respect to $x$ or something else... And yes this is incredibly *long* and tedious and convoluted.  But it *is* just the product rule and the chain rule apply again and again and again.

Comment: Suppose I wanted to write that be the chain for $(e^{x^2})' =$ the derivative of $e^y$ evaluated at $y=x^2$$ \cdot (x^2)' = e^{x^2}\cdot 2x = 2xe^{x^2}$.  That's straight forward but how am I supposed to write " the derivative of $e^y$ evaluated at $y=x^2$"? If I write $(e^{x^2})'$ that imply I want to take derivative with respect to $x$ not $x^2$ and of I wrote $(e^y)'_{y=x^2}$ or $(e^{x^2})'_{x^2}$ it would't be clear what I meant. Now I *could* use Leibnitz notation and write $\frac {d e^{x^2}}{dx^2} = e^{x^2}$ but I started the whole thing with Newton notation and I cant just switch gears.